# Doubt regarding NCB for a second hand car

Tags: india, insurance, car-insurance

I had bought a second hand car with NCB 50%. When i approached the car insurer to change the ownership name, he did the same and he didn't mention anything about the NCB transfer and I also was unaware about it. When the next renewal came,  I was charged a huge amount with 0% NCB and when I asked them, they said the previous owner had changed the NCB to his new car bought and hence I'll not get it. I said OK since I wasn't aware of it and it's my mistake.

So, my question is that will it take another 5 years for the policy  to have a 50% NCB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had bought a second hand car with NCB 50%

No claim bonus is for the driver. So it cannot be transferred to you unless you got the vehicle as legal heir.

> my question is that will it take another 5 years for the policy to have a 50% NCB ?

Yes this is right. It will take 5 years and no claims in these 5 years. It is also important to note, if you buy a new car and sell the current car, you will be able to transfer this to new vehicle and reduce the premium.